# Calling Js document.getElementById by PHP SDK $user_profile

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to use the Fb PHP SDK to execute different Js document.getElementById innerHTML functions, depending on whether the user is logged in to Fb or not. For some reason the function won't work for me. I know my API connection is successful, as I can call alternative alert functions ("you are logged in" :you are not logged in") in this way. But the getElementById function won't work. I've tried moving the script to the body etc, nothing working.

Any ideas? It's probably a rookie question, but I'd love it if there was a simple solution! Here's the essential code below...

```
<head>
<?php if ($user_profile) { ?>
<script>
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "<p>You ARE logged in</p>";

</script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "You are NOT logged in";
    </script>
<?php } ?>

  </head>

  <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div id="test1">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to not return `null` you script is looking for an id before it is loaded.

You could place you script beneath `test1`

or

Use a function and place that under `test1`

```
 <script>
   function checkIfloggedIn(){
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "<p>You ARE logged in</p>";
    }
 </script>

 <div id="test1"></div>

 <script>checkIfloggedIn()</script>
```

Or
Call your script upon `onload`